# EC2 hosted asp.net not stable

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, asp.net

I moved our web hosting to Amazon EC2.
At first everything was working well. In the last few days I have been getting this error:

```
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

This seems to be a DNS issue, and I have no idea how to deal with this.

Has anyone seen this error from an EC2 instance?

**More Info:** It is a windows instance. The look up is a reverse look up of the current machine.
The callstack looks like this:

```
     SocketException (0x2afc): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]   
    System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +7987115   
System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress) +544   
ClientDependency.Core.UriExtensions.IsLocalUri(Uri uri) +184
```

Comment: Where and in what context are you getting this error? Do you know what name is being requested? If you think it is a DNS issue, what is your server's DNS configuration? Would you care to tell us whether this is a Linux instance or a Windows instance? Unfortunately, your question in its current/original form is not answerable.

Comment: Added more info. Sorry, I was thinking maybe this is a known issue with AWS. This worked on a VPS hosted with GoDaddy for a year without error, before moveing to AWS.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426063/system-net-sockets-socketexception-the-requested-name-is-valid-but-no-data-of

Comment: @MilesErickson - 1. Not really. 2. This is a system issue, not a c# issue, since it started only after moving to AWS, and with no code changes. 3. Last, but not least: There is no answer there :)

Comment: If it worked at first, then I sincerely doubt that this is directly related to your move to EC2. The link to the duplicate question was for future reference/moderation purposes, not because I thought it would be immediately helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Windows issue that is not specific to Amazon EC2.

Others who have experienced this error message have reported resolving it in the following ways:

- Simply rebooting the server
- Resetting the Windows TCP/IP stack with `netsh int ip reset`
- Modifying the ASP.NET application's source code:  [Example 2](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/203784-Socket-exception.aspx)